# How DispatcherFrame works differently from Dispatcher.BeginInvoke in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Updating UI in WPF can be done by calling `BeginInvoke` or `Invoke` methods of `Dispatcher` class. Normally everyone use this technique to update the UI which may be fine for the user needs. But I have found a class called `DispatcherFrame` in framework to do the same.

```
DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();   
//Dispatcher.BeginInvoke code comes here
Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
```

What `DispatcherFrame` class do more on `Dispatcher`? When can we go for `DispatcherFrame`?.
Your answer is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Another question that could have been solved just by googing keyword DispatcherFrame.

Dispatcher creates automatically DispatcherFrames and places them inside a queue. Window itself is a large DispatcherFrame for example.

Only reason why you would use it is if you wish to configure your frame e.g. with some callbacks when Dispatcher is done with all the actions inside it.

Comment: Well, I googled DispatcherFrame and that's a first SO result, so bear in mind that the answers I need it. I hate it when I google things and I only get results like ' just google it, ya lazy bastard'.